# Conveyor belt tension adjustment

Tags: mechanical-engineering, conveyor

I saw this video of adjusting conveyor belt tension and I wonder how the adjustment actually works mechanically https://youtu.be/eKkJN7WkCfw?t=152

As you can see, each of the two sides can be adjusted by turning a corresponding bolt. Considering the roller is fitted on a solid shaft, wouldn't pushing one side forward cause the shaft to bend? How does the roller and its shaft change orientation when the shaft and the roller are solid?

Answer (score 1):

They use special bearings called spherical bearings which allow a lot of axle movement. There are a lot of varieties of these depending on the type of load and amount of axis accommodation required..

https://www.rexnord.com/products/bearings/link-belt-spherical-roller-bearings/bearing-inserts-unmounted-replacements/a20000